# In every src or href auto values "$1"$0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ide, atom-editor

I use Atom for a couple of months but recently I notice something strange.
Every time I write `<img>` or `<a>` and use autocomplete on src or href I have predefined values "$1"$0.

For Example:

```
<img src="$1"$0>
```

Of course, I can delete them but is annoying to do it every time.
Can you help me what can cause this?

Comment: i think this should be in superuser not in stackoverflow. CMIIW

Comment: If you really prefer to have the question moved to another section, I think it should be the "Webmasters" community rather than "superuser", because the question relies to HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I recently suffered the same issue, it was caused by myself having the `snippets` package disabled. Enabling it resolved the issue.

I found this solution here: [Snippets not expanding properly](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus/issues/661)